# Asynchronous Queue Callback from Web Request

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

I have a web app that talks to web socket thats connected to a third party service.   The socket only has one connection, given that I can have many API calls.  I am adding a message to a message queue and then process one at a time.  I put together a proof of concept below.  I'm struggling with the code that waits for the message to be processed and then calls a delegate with the response.

The basic goal is I have a message it goes through a message queue, the socket receives and responses, and then a socket message is returned back to the original request.

Anyone have any ideas for the best approach to wait for a out of context response?

This is the error I am getting, which I can understand because the message is pushed on the queue and the controller exits.

> Unhandled exception. System.ObjectDisposedException:
> IFeatureCollection has been disposed. Object name: 'Collection'.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.ThrowContextDisposed() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.ContextDisposed()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.Fetch[TFeature](TFeature& cached, Func`2 factory)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.get_HasStarted()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(HttpResponse
> response, String text, Encoding encoding, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(HttpResponse
> response, String text, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> WebApplication1.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<b__2>d.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\Users\martyspc\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Startup.cs:line
> 97
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__140_1(Object state)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
> System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class MessageProcessor
    {

        public void Process()
        {
            while (true)
            {

                try
                {
                    var message = MessageQueue.GetNextMessage();

                    message.ProcessedMessageCallBack("Hello From Messages");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Message Queue Empty");


                }

                Thread.Sleep(2000);


            }
        }

    }

    public static class MessageQueue
    {

        private static Queue<Message> Messages { get; set; } = new Queue<Message>();

        public static void AddMessage(Message message)
        {
            Messages.Enqueue(message);
        }

        public static Message GetNextMessage()
        {
            return Messages.Dequeue();
        }

    }

    public class Message
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public Action<String> ProcessedMessageCallBack { get; set; }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            var mp = new MessageProcessor();

            Thread InstanceCaller = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mp.Process));


            // Start the thread.
            InstanceCaller.Start();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    Action<string> del = async i => await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hi There");

                    MessageQueue.AddMessage(new Message() { Label = "Hello World", ProcessedMessageCallBack = del });

                });
            });


        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance, Marty.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any of that in your `Startup.cs`. Look in to `IHostedService` or `BackgroundService`.

Comment: Thank you, I think the spirit of the issue would still remain.  This is just a simple proof of concept.

Comment: Your context is going out of scope. By the time you run this line: `context.Response.WriteAsync` the request is over and that context has been disposed of.

Comment: @Andy, I see the problem I'm trying to find a solution to block until the message is processed.  A bit stuck.  Thank you.

Comment: Why have a queue then?

Comment: @Andy the web socket layer can only process one message at a time.  So I want to in a sense queue the API requests to process the messages one at a time.  They will be processed fast so keeping the request open is fine.